# Software Development Methodology

Tags: terminology, methodology

I'd like to know the difference between Software Development Process and Software Development Methodology if there is any.

Comment: You may want to accept some answers to your questions...

Answer (score 6):

A process is only a component of a methodology. A methodology has:

- A **process** aspect: what tasks are to be carried out?
- A **product** aspect: what things are to be used and/or created?
- A **people** aspect: what people and teams are going to do all this?
- A **time** aspect: how does all this get organised in time?
- A **modelling** aspect: what modelling units (language) are used to capture all this?

This is a simplified interpretation of the more formal definitions that you can find in [ISO/IEC 24744 Software Engineering - Metamodel for Development Methodologies](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO/IEC_24744).

Still, the terms "method", "methodology" and "process" are used by different people with different meanings. After 20 years working in this field, I think that trying to agree on a standard use is futile. :-)

Answer (score 4):

It's the same as the difference between [process](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/process) and [methodology](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/methodology) in any other discipline.  I think of the processes as the implementation of the methodology.

Comment: Oh! ok... So assuming Waterfal, Prototyping, SSADM, Spiral are the processes, thats if am correct. then what then could be the methodologies?

Comment: SSADM is a methodology. Prototyping applies to several methodologies, including RAD and Agile (I'll get comments about that one).  Benevolent Autocracy is the methodology for Waterfall.  Spiral is not one I am familiar with but looks like a methodology rather than a process.  You are concentrating on some fairly arbitrary semantics, are you having a problem with something?

Comment: Am getting my self prepared for an exam due 13th January.

However am trying to gather ideas from different sources to get me well prepared. Ive been reading a simple introduction from the wiki link below which stated some methodologies such as OOP,RAD,RUP,AUP etc. and some approaches which i believe are the processes such as Waterfall,Prototyping,Incremental,Spiral etc. However further down the wiki page its states other software development methodologies and includes RUP,AUP,OOD(Object Oriented Design) and OOAD(Object Oriented Analysis and Design) both of which i believe falls under OOP.

Comment: Thats when i got confused and actually wanted to find out the differences between the Methodologies and the Processes(Approaches).

Reading Source: 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Software_development_methodology

Comment: From further reading i was speculating there could probably be just two approaches to any kind of methodology namely the Waterfall and iterative but am not sure of my self. i reckon this is very confusing and can be misleading.

Answer (score 1):

The methodology is more a general mindset which sets basic parameters. A process is a concrete manifestation within the given borders of the methodology. You can think of agile as methodology and Scrum as concrete implementation.

Sometimes it's hard to distinguish between the two. As rule of thumb: If you can immediately start to work with it, it's probably a process. A methodology requires more adaptation .

Comment: Mmmmm.....would have loved to hear more...thanks anyway. It was very helpful

Comment: Oh! ok... So assuming Waterfal, Prototyping, SSADM, Spiral are the processes, thats if am correct. What then could be the methodologies?

Answer (score 0):

A more wide term would be Software Development Philosophies.
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_software_development_philosophies