# The difference between "Software development methodology" and "Software development process"

Tags: methodology

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Software Development Methodology](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2004843/software-development-methodology)

What's The difference between "Software development methodology" and "Software development process"

Comment: The difference is that the two buzzphrases end in different buzzwords.

Answer (score 2):

About $5000 a day in consultancy ;-)

Comment: Not to mention lots of expensive CASE tools ;)